# VBScript: How to utiliize a dictionary object returned from a function?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to return a dictionary from a function. I believe the function is working correctly, but I'm not sure how to utilize the returned dictionary.

Here is the relevant part of my function:

```
Function GetSomeStuff()
  '
  ' Get a recordset...
  '

  Dim stuff
  Set stuff = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  rs.MoveFirst
  Do Until rs.EOF
    stuff.Add rs.Fields("FieldA").Value, rs.Fields("FieldB").Value
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

  GetSomeStuff = stuff
End Function
```

How do I call this function and use the returned dictionary?

EDIT: I've tried this:

```
Dim someStuff
someStuff = GetSomeStuff
```

and

```
Dim someStuff
Set someStuff = GetSomeStuff
```

When I try to access someStuff, I get an error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'GetSomeStuff'
```

EDIT 2: Trying this in the function:

```
Set GetSomeStuff = stuff
```

Results in this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wasn't too sure of what was your problem, so I experimented a bit.

It appears that you just missed that to assign a reference to an object, you have to use `set`, even for a return value:

```
Function GetSomeStuff
  Dim stuff
  Set stuff = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    stuff.Add "A", "Anaconda"
    stuff.Add "B", "Boa"
    stuff.Add "C", "Cobra"

  Set GetSomeStuff = stuff
End Function

Set d = GetSomeStuff
Wscript.Echo d.Item("A")
Wscript.Echo d.Exists("B")
items = d.Items
For i = 0 To UBound(items)
  Wscript.Echo items(i)
Next
```

Comment: I was missing the combination of Set GetSOmeStuff = stuff and Set d = GetSomeStuff. Thanks!

Comment: @user66001 I don't think it is a good idea to try and edit the code (or answer!) of somebody else (beside tasks like typo fixes, URL updates, etc.), particularly for such minor point, especially when you are wrong... If you replace `d` with the function name, you call the function on each occurrence. The lack of `()` might have mislead you to use a function call like a variable. I don't see the point of creating the `stuff` structure each time. It isn't critical here, for such simple demo, but it can be important in a real program.

Comment: @PhiLho - My mistake. Sorry (Think it does matter on principle, so deleted my wrong information).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried doing
`set GetSomeStuff = stuff`
in the last line of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Dim returnedStuff
Set returnedStuff = GetSomeStuff()
```

Then "For Each" iterating over the dictionary? There's an example of using the Dictionary (albeit for VB6, the gist of it is the same though!) [here](http://www.kamath.com/tutorials/tut009_dictionary.asp).