# How do I clone a Dictionary object?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, clone

I have a `Dictionary` object in VBScript. How can I copy all the objects contained in it to a new `Dictionary`, i.e. create a clone/duplicate of the dictionary?

Answer (score 12):

Create a new `Dictionary` object, iterate through the keys in the original dictionary and adds these keys and the corresponding values to the new dictionary, like this:

```
Function CloneDictionary(Dict)
  Dim newDict
  Set newDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For Each key in Dict.Keys
    newDict.Add key, Dict(key)
  Next
  newDict.CompareMode = Dict.CompareMode

  Set CloneDictionary = newDict
End Function
```

This should be enough in most cases. However, if your original dictionary holds objects, you'll have to implement deep cloning, that is, clone these objects as well.

Comment: Yes thats true..but is there any built in functionality to perform deep cloning

Comment: Thanks this works well, strange its not part of VBA language...

Comment: Note that you need to set the `.CompareMode` **before** adding data to the new dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a VBA solution, the following function performs a "deep-clone" of a dictionary, including nested dictionary objects.

```
' Compare mode for cloning dictionary object
' See CloneDictionary function
Public Enum eCompareMethod2
    ecmBinaryCompare = 0
    ecmTextCompare = 1
    ecmDatabaseCompare = 2
    ' Added this to use original compare method
    ecmSourceMethod = 3
End Enum


'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CloneDictionary
' Author    : Adam Waller
' Date      : 3/30/2021
' Purpose   : Recursive function to deep-clone a dictionary object, including nested
'           : dictionaries.
'           : NOTE: All other object types are cloned as a reference to the same object
'           : referenced by the original dictionary, not a new object.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function CloneDictionary(dSource As Dictionary, _
    Optional Compare As eCompareMethod2 = ecmSourceMethod) As Dictionary

    Dim dNew As Dictionary
    Dim dChild As Dictionary
    Dim varKey As Variant

    ' No object returned if source is nothing
    If dSource Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    ' Create new dictionary object and set compare mode
    Set dNew = New Dictionary
    If Compare = ecmSourceMethod Then
        ' Use the same compare mode as the original dictionary.
        dNew.CompareMode = dSource.CompareMode
    Else
        dNew.CompareMode = Compare
    End If
    
    ' Loop through keys
    For Each varKey In dSource.Keys
        If TypeOf varKey Is Dictionary Then
            ' Call this function recursively to add nested dictionary
            Set dChild = varKey
            dNew.Add varKey, CloneDictionary(dChild, Compare)
        Else
            ' Add key to dictionary
            dNew.Add varKey, dSource(varKey)
        End If
    Next varKey
    
    ' Return new dictionary
    Set CloneDictionary = dNew
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just :

Set dTEM = dEQP

;)

Comment: What are these variable names `dTEM` and `dEQP`. Add an additional explanation to your answer, please.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the accepted answer in [VBScript: How to utiliize a dictionary object returned from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140002/vbscript-how-to-utiliize-a-dictionary-object-returned-from-a-function). Could be a solution if a reference is all that is being looked for.

**Edit** As per Ekkehard.Horner's comment, I understand now that this is **not cloning**, but may help others who are only looking for a reference to the original object.

Comment: Dictionaries are objects and passing objects to Subs/Functions/Methods (even with ByVal), assigning objects to values, and returning objects from Functions/Method (hopefully with Set) will *always* deal with references and never clone/copy/create a new object. So please delete your misleading/wrong answer.