# Is it possible to add a dictionary to an array in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out if this is a possibility in terms of the capability of excel. Consider the following code in what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim some_text, split_text() As String
Dim some_array_dict() As String 'This is the array to store the dictionaries
Dim some_dict As Dictionary 'The dictionaries that I'll be storing in the array above

ReDim some_array_dict(y) As String 'y is previously defined as an integer

For i = 0 To y - 1
    Set some_dict = New Dictionary

    some_text = some_array(2, i)
    split_text = Split(some_text, " ")
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(split_text)
        some_dict.Add split_text(j), 1
    Next j
    
    some_array_dict(i) = some_dict 'Issue
    
    Debug.Print some_array_dict(i) 'For debugging purposes
Next i
```

The following is the line of code that gives me the error:

```
some_array_dict(i) = some_dict
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I think Tim's solution is the only one that actually works. Be careful because [Dictionary is a reference type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022182/how-do-i-clone-a-dictionary-object) so setting each array component to the same object will result in the same object being referred by all array components. I don't think that this is what you want..

Comment: More specifically to Tim's answer, I had to `Dim` as a `Dictionary`. That actually ended up fixing the issue I was facing. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Array is declared as wrong type, and you need to use `Set` when assigning objects

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr_dict() As Object, x As Long

    ReDim arr_dict(1 To 3)
    For x = 1 To 3

        Set arr_dict(x) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

        With arr_dict(x)
            .Add "hello", 1
            .Add "there", 2
        End With

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to assign a Dictionary to a *string* array.

Try:

```
ReDim some_array_dict(y) As Dictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Dictionary` is an object, you have to use `Set` for the assignment:

```
Set some_array_dict(i) = some_dict ' No issue
```