# VBA dictionary inheritance without link

Tags: vba

I would like to have one dictionary inherit keys and values from the other. After which, if I modify one dictionary, it will not modify the other. I thought this was straight forward:

```
Sub testdic()
    Dim d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "first", 1
    Dim s
    Set s = d
    s.Add "second", 2
End Sub
```

The above code adds the key "second" and value 2 to both s and d dictionaries when I expected it to add to only the s dictionary. Is it possible to do this without creating a class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clone a Dictionary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022182/how-do-i-clone-a-dictionary-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more generic solution that does not restrict what you use for keys or values.  The function performs a "shallow copy" of the dictionary.  It returns a new dictionary object, but any objects in the original dictionary are essentially passed by reference into the new dictionary.

If the items in the original dictionary are not objects (Strings, Integers, etc.), this is a moot point.  But if the items are objects, then a change to any object that gets shallow-copied between dictionaries will change the object in "both" places (I put "both" in quotes, because there's really only a single object, just with multiple references pointing to it).

```
Function DictionaryShallowCopy(Dict As Object) As Object           ' <-- Late-bound
'Function DictionaryShallowCopy(Dict As Dictionary) As Dictionary  ' <-- Early-bound
    If Dict Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    Set DictionaryShallowCopy = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' <-- Late-bound
    'Set DictionaryShallowCopy = New Dictionary                      ' <-- Early-bound
    If Dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Dict.Keys
        DictionaryShallowCopy.Add Key, Dict.Item(Key)
    Next Key

End Function
```

The above function uses late-binding so you do not need a reference to the Scripting Runtime.  This allows you to simply drop this function into any VBA project without any trouble.  Early-binding will give you a performance boost and intellisense, so it makes sense to use it if possible.

Here's a sample procedure that illustrates what the above function does (note that the sample *requires* a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime).  If you have any questions, ask in the comments.

```
Sub Sample_DictionaryShallowCopy()
    Dim A As Dictionary, A_Nothing As Dictionary
    Set A_Nothing = DictionaryDeepCopy(A)
    Debug.Print A_Nothing Is Nothing
    'True

    Set A = New Dictionary

    Dim A0 As Dictionary
    Set A0 = DictionaryDeepCopy(A)

    A.Add "Texas", "Austin"
    A.Add "New York", "Albany"

    Dim B As Dictionary
    Set B = DictionaryShallowCopy(A)
    B.Add "Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"

    Debug.Print A0.Count, A.Count, B.Count
    ' 0             2             3

    Dim C As New Dictionary
    C.Add A, "Dictionary A"
    C.Add B, "Dictionary B"
    Dim D As Dictionary
    Set D = DictionaryShallowCopy(C)
    'The Key type is maintained during the copy, even if the key is an object:
    Debug.Print TypeName(C.Keys(0)), TypeName(D.Keys(0))
    'Dictionary    Dictionary

    Dim E As New Dictionary
    E.Add "DictA", A

    Dim F As Dictionary
    Set F = DictionaryShallowCopy(E)
    F.Add "DictB", B

    F("DictA")("Texas") = "Houston"
    'This is a shallow copy, so the items that are objects are
    '    "copied" by reference, not by value:
    Debug.Print A("Texas"), E("DictA")("Texas"), F("DictA")("Texas")
    'Houston       Houston       Houston

    'If this were a DeepCopy, then the above line would have outputted:
    'Austin        Austin        Houston
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice catch.  You're right, this is really a shallow copy.  A generic deep copy of a dictionary would be impossible because you would have no way of knowing how to deep copy the objects in the dictionary.

Comment: This works well for me as my keys won't actually be integers as is required in RubberDuck's answer. Will have to do some extra reading on deep v shallow copies though; can you briefly explain what limitations I might experience with this method?

Comment: @jm158: I added some additional code and comments to the sample procedure in my answer to show the difference between a deep and shallow copy.  The main limitation is that if you are storing objects in your dictionary, they are still being "copied" by reference and not by value.  So a change to an object in one dictionary will update the object in the copied dictionary.  This is because you're not really copying the objects in the dictionary at all...just the references to the objects.

Comment: If you were truly motivated you *could* create a deep copy function, but it would not work with generic dictionary objects.  You would need to create a custom dictionary class that only accepted objects that Implemented a DeepCopy method.  You could do this by having an iDeepCopy class with an empty `Function DeepCopy() As iDeepCopy` function.  Then any objects you added to the dictionary would have to include `Implements iDeepCopy` in the declarations section of their class module.  At that point, though, you start pushing the limits of what you can/should be doing in VBA.

Comment: @mwolfe02 I don't know that I agree with your assessment that it would be pushing the limits of what can or should be done in VBA. The custom dict class sounds very reasonable to me. It depends on what OP really wants to store in the dict. Now [***this*** is pushing the limits of what can/should be done in VBA](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66706/wait-is-this-linq).

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you would need to switch your key and value around, so that the integer is the key, and the string is the value. Something along these lines.

```
Sub testdic()
    Dim d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add 1, "first"
    Dim s
    Set s = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i as long
    For i = 0 to d.Items.Count -1
        s(i) = d.Items(i)
    Next i

    s.Add 2, "second"
End Sub
```

[This question about iterating items in a dictionary may also be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11296522/3198973).

Comment: No way around iterating over the items? Any idea why "set" creates a link between the objects? Thanks

Comment: That's just basic object reference stuff. The variable doesn't hold the actual object. It just holds a *reference* to the object.

Comment: @jm158 I'd say the important part is the two distinct calls to `CreateObject` - if you want two distinct instances of an object, you need to create two distinct references. Otherwise you're only *setting* a reference to point to another, with the two handles pointing to the same object.