# Returning an dictionary object from a function in VBA

Tags: vba

I have the following declaration in a function in VBA:

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

When I try to return dict using the code `GetDates = dict` I get an error. Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [Can a VBScript function return a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038058/can-a-vbscript-function-return-a-dictionary) and [VBScript: How to utiliize a dictionary object returned from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140002/vbscript-how-to-utiliize-a-dictionary-object-returned-from-a-function) - VBA and VBScript are the same in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set GetDates = dict
```

You have to use Set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't appear to work. I am calling it like this: ResetDates = GetDates(1, 12, "Client Next Reset Date", "Client Roll Date", "Cur Not.")

Comment: where Set ResetDates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Comment: vCould you update your question with the extra code and quote your error message?

Comment: You need one more "Set": `Set ResetDates = GetDates(1, 12, ..., "")`

Comment: Everytime you want to associate a variable with an (dictionary) object, you need to use SET.

Comment: @Paul, if this worked, then click on the check mark that appears on the upper left of this answer to 'accept it'. Thanks.